# how to read another exe's app.config file - as name value pairs

Tags: .net, config

To read the AppSettings section from your current application's app.config is easy - you can just use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings, which returns a series of name/value pairs you can read.

But what if you want to access the entries from another application's config file?

I see ConfigurationManager has other methods like OpenExeConfiguration, but when I follow these methods all the way down, I don't see any way to iterate over an AppSetting (or any section for that matter) as a series of name/value pairs, such as is available with ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.

Is it possible to read a separate exe's config files and easily iterate (not just access by individual keys)?

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a cleaner way to do this, but this works (showing both grabbing a specific value and building a dictionary so you can iterate).

```
    private string collection;
    Dictionary<string, string> settings = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    // using System.Configuration;
    private void LoadOthersConfig(string exepath)
    {
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exepath);
        if (config.Sections["appSettings"] != null)
        {
            AppSettingsSection appSettings = (AppSettingsSection)config.GetSection("appSettings");

            collection = appSettings.Settings["collection"].Value;

            foreach (string k in appSettings.Settings.AllKeys)
            {
                settings.Add(k, appSettings.Settings[k].Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This helped with minor tweaks

Answer (score 0):

Application configuration files are XML files, so you could parse them using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).  This would allow you to easily read an application configuration file and get any information you chose from it.